# Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, html

```
$card = mysqli_query(" $db, SELECT * FROM `products`");
```

ошибка

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted
>   to string in F:\OSPanel\domains\chp\assets\php\config.php on line 8

ссылается на этот запрос, помогите исправить пожалуйста, пол часа уже не могу понять в чем дело

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объект $db вы пытались вывести как строку из-за этого и ошибка.

Вот решение

```
$card = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `products`");
```